# Are these valid email addresses?

Tags: validation, email, url, uri, email-address

I found [this samples of URL and email address](http://yellow5.us/firefox/testcases.txt), and found these.

```
1. user@subdomain.example.com/test/
2. user:password@subdomain.example.com
3. user:password@subdomain.example.com/test/index.html
```

Are these valid(possible) email addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addresses are illegal.

The local part of an email adress can not contain : except in a quoted part.

The domainname has to be a valid hostname, and as such can not include directory.

As idipous notes the linked page does not indicate that these should be interpreted as email adresses.

Answer (score 1):

These are not email addresses. These are ssh connection statements or http connections  or with no protocol at all pointing to a particular directory on the server. For example if you want to use scp you write something like

```
scp test.txt user@myhost:/dirtocopyto
```